# What concrete type does 'yield return' return?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, yield-return

What is the concrete type for this `IEnumerable<string>`?

```
private IEnumerable<string> GetIEnumerable()
{
    yield return "a";
    yield return "a";
    yield return "a";
}
```

Comment: This is a syntactic sugar. a lot is going on under the hood. The faster way to see it is to use the reflector. It basically creates a class which keeps a state, and returns "a" when `GetNext()` or something like that is called.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a compiler-generated type. The compiler generates an `IEnumerator<string>` implementation that returns three "a" values and an `IEnumerable<string>` skeleton class that provides one of these in its `GetEnumerator` method.

The generated code looks *something* like this*:

```
// No idea what the naming convention for the generated class is --
// this is really just a shot in the dark.
class GetIEnumerable_Enumerator : IEnumerator<string>
{
    int _state;
    string _current;

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        switch (_state++)
        {
            case 0:
                _current = "a";
                break;
            case 1:
                _current = "a";
                break;
            case 2:
                _current = "a";
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public string Current
    {
        get { return _current; }
    }

    object IEnumerator.Current
    {
        get { return Current; }
    }

    void IEnumerator.Reset()
    {
        // not sure about this one -- never really tried it...
        // I'll just guess
        _state = 0;
        _current = null;
    }
}

class GetIEnumerable_Enumerable : IEnumerable<string>
{
    public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new GetIEnumerable_Enumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Or maybe, as SLaks says in his answer, the two implementations end up in the same class. I wrote this based on my choppy memory of generated code I'd looked at before; really, one class would suffice, as there's no reason the above functionality requires two.

In fact, come to think of it, the two implementations really *should* fall within a single class, as I just remembered the functions that use `yield` statements must have a return type of *either* `IEnumerable<T>` **or** `IEnumerator<T>`.

Anyway, I'll let you perform the code corrections to what I posted mentally.

<sub>*This is purely for illustration purposes; I make no claim as to its real accuracy. It's only to demonstrate in a general way how the compiler does what it does, based on the evidence I've seen in my own investigations.</sub>

Comment: Furthermore, the compiler-generated type will have the name `<GetIEnumerable>d__0` in your example. (Yes, the `<` and `>` are part of the *type name*. You can’t write such a type name in C#, but it’s valid in the CLR.) The type is nested inside the type that declares the `GetIEnumerable()` method.

Answer (score 9):

The compiler will automatically generate a class that implements both `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerator<T>` (in the same class).

[Jon Skeet has a detailed explanation](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter6/IteratorBlockImplementation.aspx).

Comment: Please add the relevant parts of the link to your answer

Answer (score 3):

The concrete implementation of `IEnumerable<string>` returned by the method is an anonymous type generated by the compiler

```
Console.WriteLine(GetIEnumerable().GetType());
```

Prints :

```
YourClass+<GetIEnumerable>d__0
```