# Finding Type of IEnumerable object

Tags: c#

For most objects I can do,

```
obj.getType().FullName
```

But for the following code,

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IEnumerable<int> em = get_enumerable();
            Console.WriteLine(em.GetType());
            Console.Read();
        }

        static IEnumerable<int> get_enumerable()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                yield return i;
            }
        }
```

Output is,

> ConsoleApplication1.Program+d__0

Where ConsoleApplication1 is assembly and Program is containing class (not shown). Why doesn't it show IEnumerable and how can I make the GetType more descriptive for this case?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What concrete type does 'yield return' return?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454395/what-concrete-type-does-yield-return-return)

Comment: @James: That's not a duplicate; he's asking how to inspect the iterator type.

Answer (score 8):

`IEnumerable<T>` is an *open generic type*.  It isn't an actual type; it's merely a function that constructs concrete (*closed*) generic types like `IEnumerable<int>`.

`IEnumerable<int>` is an interface; it is impossible to have an instance of an interface.

Your iterator function actually returns an instance of a hidden compiler-generated class that implements `IEnumerable<int>`; that's what you're seeing from `GetType()`.

You want to find the generic type parameter of the type's `IEnumerable<T>` implementation:

```
em.GetType().GetInterface("System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1")
            .GetGenericArguments()[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

`IEnumerable` is an interface, but `GetType` will return the `System.Type` that represents the class of the object, not the interface(s) it implements.

When you use `yield return`, the C# compiler automagically generates a new class (named `ConsoleApplication1.Program+d__0` in this case) which implements `IEnumerable<int>` (and `IEnumerable`).