# What happens to GetEnumerator() method when yield return is used?

Tags: c#, collections, enumerator, yield-return

Learning the collections and IEnumerable and IEnumerator interfaces.
I have the below program. WHen i step into the

```
IEnumerator<string> name = sample.GetEnumerator();
```

it calls the `Console.WriteLine("inside getenumerator");`

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SampleStrings sample = new SampleStrings();
            IEnumerator<string> name = sample.GetEnumerator();
            foreach (var item in sample)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    class SampleStrings : IEnumerable<string>
    {
        public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("inside getenumerator");

            return null;//for testing purpose only
        }

        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return this.GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
```

Now if I replace the GetEnumerator as below when the same `IEnumerator<string> name = sample.GetEnumerator();`
is called then it does not step into the function. I would expect it to step into the function but not return anything since i did not call `movenext()` yet.
What is happening when i specify yield that makes it behave this way. The program works.

```
public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("inside getenumerator");
            yield return "First";
            yield return "Second";

        }
```

Comment: Your 'before' code doesn't compile (you can't have `"Test"` as the return value from a function with return type `IEnumerator<string>`)

Comment: @AakashM: Updated the code. That before code was just to check the functionality. I am not really using the return values. Is my question clear. I know it is a little tricky.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The code of an `IEnumerator` containing `yield` is converted in two parts.

A new `IEnumerator` class is created, which contains your original code, albeit rewritten so that it executes as you'd expect. *This is where your original code, include the `Console.WriteLine` lives.*

The `GetEnumerator()` method contains brand-new generated code that simply instantiates the `IEnumerator` defined above and returns it.

As a consequence, *none of your code* runs before the first `MoveNext()` is called.

This is why you'd often see the following pattern, e.g. to perform arguments validation immediately. The implementation is split in two parts: a normal method and a method containing `yield`.

```
public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator(string whatever)
{
  // Perform validation immediately when called
  if (whatever == null) throw new ArgumentException();
  return GetEnumeratorInternal(whatever);
}

private IEnumerator<int> GetEnumeratorInternal(string whatever)
{
  // Everything in this method happens on first MoveNext
  yield return 1;
  yield return 2;
}
```

Comment: Still digesting the answer. Understood part of it.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the "The GetEnumerator() method contains brand-new generated code that simply instantiates the IEnumerator defined above and returns it." Statement.

Comment: What I meant is: once compiled, the `GetEnumerator()` method does not match any of your C# code anymore. It contains something equivalent to `return new GeneratedEnumeratorClass()`. _Your_ generator code has been compiled into `GeneratedEnumeratorClass.MoveNext()`. This is why when you call a generator method (one that uses the `yield` keyword), none of this code executes. It first executes during the first `MoveNext` call.

Comment: @ckv See [what-concrete-type-does-yield-return-return](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454395/what-concrete-type-does-yield-return-return)