# IEnumerable yield return function with excel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ienumerable

I start in C #, as well as in the use of Interop.

**My goal** was to create a windows application that can return the value of the Excel.

**My problem** is that when it came to making a loop, I ended up with only the first value because the "return" closed the loop.

**What i did** To try to solve this I used "IEnumerable" on my function while keeping the type "string".

**return of function** SDExpFormsApp1.Excel+d__6

i dont understand why the return is the the name of the class following by "d__6"

I tried to find something interesting here :
https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerator-1?view=netcore-3.1

My event fucntion

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        string filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        int sheet = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        Excel excel = new Excel(filename, sheet);
        string SuperClass = excel.ReadCell(1, 1);
        string ClassName = excel.ReadCell(2, 1);
        string ClassLabel = excel.ReadCell(3, 1);
        string AttrName = excel.ReadCell2(8, 1).ToString();
        richTextBox1.Text =  "" + AttrName;

    }
```

My function to read the excel

```
public IEnumerable<string> ReadCell2(int i, int j)
    {
        try
        {

            while (ws.Cells[i, j].Value2 != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ws.Cells[i, j].Value2);
                yield return ws.Cells[i, j].Value2;
                i++;
            }
        }
        finally
        {

        }
        yield return "nothing";
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ToString` is not usually overloaded for collection/enumerables and returns type name by default and will not enumerate underlying `IEnumerable`, so you need to use `string.Join`:

```
string AttrName = string.Join("", excel.ReadCell2(8, 1));
```

As for why `ToString` returns `SDExpFormsApp1.Excel+d__6` in this particular case - it is because `yield return` is actually a syntactic sugar and compiler will generate `IEnumerable<T>` implementation for you which will have containing type name as a part of it's own. You can read more about it in answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454395/what-concrete-type-does-yield-return-return) question for example.

Comment: @SantaaClauss was glad to help!

Comment: i tried to join and splice after to convert in list `var AttrName = string.Join("/",excel.ReadCell2(8, 1));
                    var AttrName2 = AttrName.Split('/').ToList();`

Comment: it is possible to return a list with yield?

Comment: @SantaaClauss why do you need `List`? You can turn `IEnumerable` into list via `ToList`

Comment: i need a lsit to return `String: 01 String : 02 String: 03` but not in only one string

Comment: @SantaaClauss you need to ask a question like this: "i have enumerable of strings, containing for example `["str1", "str2"]` and as a result i want to get ....."

Comment: Yes sorry, it was not clear I'm not used to it yet.

Comment: also i want to return ["str1", "str2"] because i use replace method `Replace("pro", "Attr" + myEnumerable)`

Comment: @SantaaClauss what does `"Attr" + myEnumerable` mean? You have here the same error as in this post and  changing `myEnumerable` to list will not achieve anything

Comment: MyEnumerable is my function `IEnumerable<string> myEnumerable = excel.ReadCell2(8, 1);
                    List<string> myList = myEnumerable.ToList();` Attr is just a string to concat with each string of the return like that `["Attrstr1", "Attrstr2"]`

Comment: @SantaaClauss the use `myEnumerable.Select(s => "Attr" + s)`. It does not have anything to do with `myEnumerable` being `List` not  `IEnumerable`.

Comment: it's impossible to convert the result ? or to return a list or array?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215304/discussion-between-guru-stron-and-santaa-clauss).